# How to delete a node that has been found

Tags: java, methods, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree where i have to delete a node. The node has already been found, so i don't need to traverse and find the specific node. All i need is to delete a node, which is taken as an arguement.

I have started the the node remove method and currently only done how to delete a node if it has no children or is a leaf node. How do i implement a java code which will delete if it has 1 children or a parent?

my current remove method:

```
public void removeHelper(Node focus){

        if(focus.leftChild == null && focus.rightChild == null){ 
            focus = null;
        }

        // if the node has 1 child


        // if the node has 2 children


    }
```

Comment: This could get messy.  What if the node to be removed is the head of the tree?  You will probably have to make some assumptions about how you want to rebalance/restructure your tree here.

Comment: So, I will need another method to balance the tree after node removal right?

Comment: Whether you want/need a separate method is really up to you, but yes I think there could be some structural changes here.

Comment: Is this method in the Node class, or somewhere else?

Comment: This is somewhere else. Im creating a program which will store millions on words so using a remove method to remove the specific word.

Comment: @karthi97 so I guess it's in a class that holds the root of the tree?

Comment: @MauricePerry Thats right. I just need help on how to code on removing a code that has only child and 2 children. I understand how to do it for no children. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to travel down the tree, because you will need to replace the root field, or either the `leftChild` or `rightChild` of the parent node.

To remove a node that has both `leftChild` and `rightChild` not null, you can replace the node with either the rightmost node of the left subtree, or the leftmost node of the right subtree.

In this example, I assume that the methods are in a class (`Tree`?) that have a `Node` field called `root`, and that the `Node`s have a field `value` that is a `Comparable`:

```
public void remove(Node focus) {
    root = removeHelper(root, focus);
}

public static Node removeHelper(Node root, Node focus) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (root == focus) {
        if (focus.leftChild == null) {
            return focus.rightChild;
        } else if (focus.rightChild == null) {
            return focus.leftChild;
        } else {
            Node node = removeLeftMostOfRight(focus);
            node.leftChild = focus.leftChild;
            node.rightChild = focus.rightChild;
            return node;
        }
    } else {
        int r = focus.value.compareTo(root.value);
        if (r < 0) {
            root.leftChild = removeHelper(root.leftChild, focus);
        } else {
            root.rightChild = removeHelper(root.rightChild, focus);
        }
        return root;
    }
}

private static Node removeLeftMostOfRight(Node focus) {
    Node node = focus.rightChild;
    if (node.leftChild == null) {
        focus.rightChild = node.rightChild;
    } else {
        Node prev;
        do {
            prev = node;
            node = node.leftChild;
        } while (node.leftChild != null);
        prev.leftChild = node.rightChild;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Note that in languages like C/C++ you can have pointers to pointer, that allow a much simpler and more efficient implementation of binary trees.